# How to fix an error in a Mercurial changeset comment?

Tags: mercurial

Is there a way to rewrite the `hg commit` message if the wrong information was entered? We always include our Bug ID when we commit a changeset. For instance:

`hg commit -m "Bug 14585: LastName field should be mandatory"`

But If I put the wrong bug ID, is there a way (through an extension maybe) to fix the comment once the changeset has been committed and pushed to a central repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [histedit](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HisteditExtension) extension might be what you are looking for.  It allows you to edit commit messages after the fact.  It also allows you to drop or fold revisions, much like `git rebase --interactive`.

Note that you have to enable and use the extension on the repo you'd like to fix; there is no way to edit the history of a remote repo.  Additionally, I'd be very cautious about using this on a central repo.  As Tim Post points out, mercurial changesets are not meant to be changed.

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't done *anything* else to your repository, you can do an "hg rollback" and just re-commit.

Comment: What if we find the error several days later and the changeset has already been pushed to a centra repo? Can we fix it at the central repo level?

Comment: No, unless you rewrite history, but you probably don’t want to be doing that on a central repository. Doing that will require every developer pull a fresh copy of the repository. A small mistake like this isn’t worth it, just let it be :).

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to fix a commit message **IF** the incorrect changeset is still the tip of the repo.

Suppose changeset 24 has an invalid comment. Also suppose that file1.txt was involved in that changeset. You can commit a fake change to file1.txt and then collapse the fake changeset with the incorrect changeset and provide a new message.

```
cd centralrepo
echo  >> file.txt
hg commit -m "fake commit"

hg collapse 24:25 -m "Bug 14555: LastName field should be mandatory"
```

It's a hack but it does the job and leaves no trace of the correction. It would probably not be too hard to create an extension to do that and turn this into an easy to use solution.

Comment: That is a very roundabout to do it, using rollback, histedit or mq is much better.

Comment: The downvote is a bit hard. It's my own question and I'm posting my own findings here. And I clearly said it's a hack....

Answer (score 2):

If a rollback & re-commit isn't an option, or you have already pushed your changes upstream, so the [histedit extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HisteditExtension) on its own won't help, then mercurials *immutable history* will cause you problems. Whatever you do you will be left with either hanging branches which are explicitly [poisoned](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PoisonedChangesetsPlan) unwanted changesets might be re-injected into your repository at any time.

### Fixing errors

If you are in this situations then you have a couple of options, depending on how far the changes have propagated and how far back the changeset is.

I have used both of these methods in the past.

#### Fix with a sibling branch and deprecate/strip the old one

If it is only a few changesets, and you can't use the hitsedit extension for some reason, you could export those changesets as patches and re-apply them to the parent. For the first changeset (the one whose history you want to change) you will need to use `hg patch --no-commit`, and then `hg commit` with the new message. Then for the rest, just use `hg patch` to import the changes and the commit message as-is.

The problem with this method is that you end up with two branches, one of which you will need to ignore forever (I would update to the faulty changeset and tag the branch as deprecated before switching back to the fixed branch).

Alternatively, you need to find every repository which contains this branch and `hg strip` it. The problem here is that some machines might not have the Mercurial Queues extension enabled and if you miss even one repo, and that repo is synced with another, the changes start to re-propogate.

#### Fix with a child branch and merge in subsequent changes

If the changeset has already propagated too far, you could try updating to the affected revision, forcing a dummy commit and in that commit message, explain what was wrong with the previous commit message. This changeset can then be merged with your current branch tip to bring everything up to date.

For instance, if the incorrect message was "Closes #5234" and it should have been "Closes #5324" then the child message could be "Uncloses #5234, Closes #5324".

Answer (score 1):

Changesets in Mercurial are deliberately *immutable*. If you have committed since that, no, you can't change that revision's files. However, there is a guide to [edit the history](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EditingHistory), but take very, very *very* good care to not screw up your repo in the process.

It seems like you just want to edit the commit message, which you may be able to do.